# How to return a Result<Unit> from fetch and save database operation

Tags: android, kotlin, try-catch, repository-pattern

### Scenario

I have a function `add()`which fetches data from `remoteDataSource` and, if successful, saves it it to `localDataSource`.

When I try to return the result I am getting error `Type mismatch. Required: Result<Unit> Found: Result<Foo>`.

I believe this is because `remoteDataSource.fetch()` is returning `Result<Foo>` and not my nested `Result.success/failure()`

How can I get `add()` to return the nested `Result<Unit>`?

Note I am using the Kotlin `Return` type.

```
suspend fun add(csv: String): Result<Unit> {
    return try {
        remoteDataSource.fetch(csv) /*<---remoteDataSource.fetch() returns Result<Foo>*/
            .onSuccess { result ->
                localDataSource.save(result) /*<---localDataSource.save() returns Result<Unit>*/
                    .onSuccess {
                        Result.success(Unit)
                    }
                    .onFailure {
                        Result.failure<Unit>(Throwable(it))
                    }
            }
            .onFailure {
                Result.failure<Unit>(Throwable(it))
            }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        Result.failure(e)
    }
}
```

### Update

I have discovered the `fold()` function which is able to transform the result returned by `onSuccess{...}`. However I am not sure if this is correctly capturing throwables in both `remoteDataSource` and `LocalDataSource`. Please confirm if this is a viable solution or if another approach should be used.

```
override suspend fun add(csv: String): Result<Unit> {
    return try {
        remoteDataSource.fetch(csv)
            .onSuccess { result ->
                localDataSource.save(result)
            }.fold(
                onSuccess = { Result.success(Unit) },
                onFailure = { Result.failure(Throwable()) }
            )
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        Result.failure(e)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this using Retrofit?

Comment: @cutiko `remoteDataSource` is using Retrofit. `localDataSource` is using Room.

Answer (score 1):

The methods `onSuccess` and `onFailure` are callbacks, so you are not returning `Result` at all but returning whatever `onFailure` is returning, probably `Void`.

Please make sure your `interface` is making the request with a `suspend` method and is returning a `Response`.

Then you can do like this:

```
suspend fun add(csv: String): Result<Unit> {
    return try {
        val response = remoteDataSource.fetch(csv)
        if (response.isSuccesfull) {
             localDataSource.save(response.body)
             Result.success(Unit)
        } else Result.failure(RunTimeException("${response.code}"))
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        Result.failure(e)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Have you seen the update I provided in OP? Would really appreciate your review to see if `fold()` is a valid solution. I like how it encapsulates success and failure scenarios, just not sure if it is correctly capturing for both `fetch()` and `save()`. Maybe it could be combined with your answer.

Comment: Documentation doesn't seem to indicate it does what is trying to do here, maybe is the same name in another library https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/fold.html @mairs8

Comment: Here is the documentation (https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/fold.html). I think it would be suitable in this case. Do you agree?

Comment: I think the right way to write it would be `remoteDataSource.fetch(csv).fold...` but that still won't work because `onSuccess` from Retrofit is a callback.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation, the Unit is equal to void. So it throws as an error in this part if you want it as Generic POJO you have to mention it as `<T>` instead of `<Unit>`

> For Common, JVM, JS The type with only one value: the Unit object.
> This type corresponds to the **void** type in Java.